# How to check negative value returning from LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-3.5

I am using LINQ to get my correct data,inside this LINQ am calling one method to check the date difference.If the date difference goes negative LINQ returns me anonymous type.How I can handle this and how I will get this negative number as I aslo need this to my further use.

```
var daysCount = (from projCount in dtExpiring.AsEnumerable()
                 where projCount.Field<int>("AccountId") == accId
                 && (checkDate(projCount.Field<DateTime>("ValidFor"))) <= 5
                 && (checkDate(projCount.Field<DateTime>("ValidFor"))) >= 0
                 select new { daysRemain = (checkDate(projCount.Field<DateTime>("ValidFor"))) }).Distinct();
```

```
private int checkDate(DateTime validFor)
{
    try
    {
         DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
          int diffDays = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round((validFor - date).TotalDays));

          return diffDays;
      }
      catch (Exception)
      {
           return 0;
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: If I understood it correctly then your current LINQ query is not returning negative days difference and you want that as well. If that is the case then you have to remove the check

```
&& (checkDate(projCount.Field<DateTime>("ValidFor"))) >= 0
```

since it is only selecting records with 0 or positive number of days.

---

*(Old Answer)*

You can select `AccountID` as well in your anonymous object, so that you can relate the returned difference with a record. something like:

```
select new { daysRemain = (checkDate(projCount.Field<DateTime>("ValidFor"))),
             accID =  projCount.Field<int>("AccountId"})
```

and then:

```
foreach(var item in daysCount)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("{0},{1}", item.accID, item.daysRemain);
}
```

To get AccIDs for negative number you can try:

```
var negativeAccIDs = daysCount.Where(r=> r.daysRemain < 0);
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply,but I don't want the AccountId.I want the difference from the two date that is date ValidFor and current date.If possible can you suggest me the correction in my LINQ query?

Comment: @gofor.net, are you looking to get negative number of days from the query as well, if that is the case then remove your check `&& (checkDate(projCount.Field<DateTime>("ValidFor"))) >= 0`. I have updated the answer as well